# Edge-finding and Connectivity Algorithm

Tags: plot

My background and the origin of my problem are from biomedical research, so I am not an adept programmer. I have a situation where I would like to smooth the outer surface of a 2D mesh. Laplacian smoothing looks like a good choice for my needs, but I notice it requires me to write a connectivity algorithm for my mesh. For example, I would want the following coordinates

[image]

To be connected like so

([image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkVUQ.png]).

Now, I recognize that another way of connecting these points could be connected is like this

[image]

Does anyone have some advice on A) how to develop a connectivity algorithm for said points?
And B) what kind of weights/parameters might I be able to include to promote the algorithm to make connections like in the first example, as opposed to the second. One thought I had was trying to maximize area, but not sure how that would look like.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to find the bounding polygon.

Comment: Why do you prefer the first result to the second?

Comment: Your example results are both concave polygons.  If you have many points, then this is hard to calculate.  How about the convex containing polygon?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the convex bounding polygon.

[image]

The simplest way to find that is to implement the Gift Wrapping algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm )

Here is some c++ code for that

```
void cWrap::wrap()
{
    vWrap.clear();

    // find leftmost point
    cxy leftmost = vPoints[0];
    for (cxy &p : vPoints)
        if (p.x < leftmost.x)
            leftmost = p;
    vWrap.push_back(leftmost);

    // wrap around points
    cxy prev = cxy(leftmost.x, leftmost.y - 1);
    cxy last = leftmost;
    for (;;)
    {
        // loop over points
        cxy next = vPoints[0];
        double amin = 10;
        for (cxy &maybe : vPoints)
        {

            double a =
                2 * 3.142 - cxy::clockwise(
                                prev,
                                last,
                                maybe);

            if (a < 0.01)
                continue;

            // save point with least clockwise turn
            if (a < amin)
            {
                amin = a;
                next = maybe;
            }
        }
        // check if back at start
        if (next == leftmost)
            return;

        // save point
        vWrap.push_back(next);
        prev = last;
        last = next;
    }
}
```

Complete application code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/GiftWrap